# How to use member predicate to specify constraints in prolog

Tags: prolog, clpfd, constraint-programming

I'm trying to write a Prolog program which does the following:
I have some relations defined in the Relations list. (For example: [f1,s1] means f1 needs s1) Depending on what features(f1,f2,f3) are selected in the TargetFeat list, I would like to create Result list using constraint programming.
Here is a sample code:

```
Relations =[[f1, s1], [f2, s2], [f3, s3], [f3, s4]],
TargetFeat = [f3, f1],
Result = [],
member(f3,TargetFeat) #= member(s3,Result), %One of the constraints
labeling(Result).
```

This doesn't work because #= works only with arithmetic expressions as operands. What are the alternatives to achieve something like this ?

Answer (score 2):

There are many possible ways to model such dependencies with constraints. I consider in this post CLP(FD) and CLP(B) constraints, because they are most commonly used for solving combinatorial tasks.

Consider first CLP(FD), which is more frequently used and more convenient in many ways. When using CLP(FD) constraints, you again have several options to represent your task. However, no matter which model you eventually choose, you must first switch all items in your representation to suitable entitites that the constraint solver can actually reason about. In the case of CLP(FD), this means switching your entities to **integers**.

Translating your entities to corresponding integers is very straight-forward, and it is one of the reasons why CLP(FD) constraints also suffice to model tasks over domains that actually do not contain integers, but can be mapped to integers. So, let us suppose you are not reasoning about features `f1`, `f2` and `f3`, but about **integers** `0`, `1`, and `2`, or any other set of integers that suits you.

You can directly translate your requirements to this new domain. For example, instead of:

> `[f1,s1]` means: `f1` needs `s1`

we can say for example:

> `0 -> 3` means: `0` needs `3`

And this brings us already very close to CLP(FD) constraints that let us model the whole problem. We only need to make one more mental leap to obtain a representation that lets us model all requirements. Instead of *concrete* integers, we now use **CLP(FD) variables** to indicate whether or not a specific requirement must be met to obtain the desired features. We shall use the variables `R1`, `R2`, `R3`, ... to denote which requirements are needed, by using either `0` (not needed) or `1` (needed) for each of the possible requirements.

At this point, you must develop a clear mental model of what you actually want to describe. I explain what I have in mind: I want to describe a **relation** between three things:

1. a list `Fs` of **features**
2. a list `Ds` of **dependencies** between features and requirements
3. a list `Rs` of **requirements**

We have already considered how to represent all these entitites: (1) is a list of **integers** that represent the features we want to obtain. (2) is a list of `F -> R` pairs that mean "feature `F` needs requirement `R`", and (3) is a list of Boolean variables that indicate whether or not each requirement is eventually needed.

Now let us try to relate all these entitites to one another.

First things first: If no features are desired, it all is trivial:

```
features_dependencies_requirements([], _, _).
```

But what if a feature is actually desired? Well, it's simple: We only need to take into account the dependencies of that feature:

```
features_dependencies_requirements([F|Fs], Ds, Rs) :-
    member(F->R, Ds),
```

so we have in `R` the requirement of feature `F`. Now we only need to find the suitable variable in `Rs` that denotes requirement `R`. But how do we find the right variable? After all, a Prolog variable "does not have a bow tie", or—to foreigners—*lacks* a mark by which we could distinguish it from others. So, at this point, we would actually find it convenient to be able to nicely pick a variable out of `Rs` given the name of its requirement. Let us hence suppose that we represent `Rs` as a list of **pairs** of the form `I=R`, where `I` is the integer that defines the requirement, and `R` is the Boolean indicator that denotes whether that requirement is needed. Given this representation, we can define the clause above in its entirety as follows:

```
features_dependencies_requirements([F|Fs], Ds, Rs) :-
    member(F->I, Ds),
    member(I=1, Rs),
    features_dependencies_requirements(Fs, Ds, Rs).
```

That's it. This fully relates a list of features, dependencies and requirements in such a way that the third argument indicates which requirements are necessary to obtain the features.

At this point, the attentive reader will see that *no CLP(FD) constraints whatsoever* were actually used in the code above, and in fact the translation of features to integers was completely unnecessary. We can as well use atoms to denote features and requirements, using the *exact same code* shown above.

Sample query and answers:

```
?- features_dependencies_requirements([f3,f1], 
                                      [f1->s1,f2->s2,f3->s3,f3->s4],
                                      [s1=S1,s2=S2,s3=S3,s4=S4]).
S1 = S3, S3 = 1 ;
S1 = S4, S4 = 1 ;
false.
```

Obviously, I have made the following assumption: The dependencies are *disjunctive*, which means that the feature can be implemented if at least *one* of the requirements is satisifed. If you want to turn this into a conjunction, you will obviously have to change this. You can start by representing dependencies as `F -> [R1,R2,...R_n]`.

Other than that, can it still be useful to translate your entitites do integers? **Yes**, because many of your constraints can likely be formulated also with CLP(FD) constraints, and you need *integers* for this to work.

To get you started, here are two ways that may be usable in your case:

- use constraint **reification** to express what implies what. For example: `F #==> R`.
- use global constraints like `table/2` that express relations.

Particularly in the first case, CLP(B) constraints may also be useful. You can always use Boolean variables to express whether a requirement must be met.

Comment: Hi Mat, Thank you so much for this detailed answer. I'm new to Prolog and it really helped me. I have a doubt though. I'm not sure I understand these lines. "Let us hence suppose that we represent Rs as a list of pairs of the form I=R, where I is the integer that defines the requirement, and R is the Boolean indicator that denotes whether that requirement is needed". I spent some time thinking about it. But not sure what it means.

Comment: `I=R` is the term `=(I, R)`. So, for example, we expect to see `s3=1` to occur in the third list **iff** requirement `s3` must be met. For this reason, I call this an *indicator*: You can use `0` to denote that a requirement need *not* be met, and `1` for the other case.

Comment: Nit: `member(F->I, Ds)` is invalid syntax. Only SWI does accept it.

Comment: Changing F->I to F -> [R1,R2,...R_n] would force all the features to be dependant on multiple requirements, right ? I want to support something like this: [f1->s1,f2->s2,f3->[s3,s4]]

Comment: @user2139876: Only SWI allows this noncomforming syntax. For an ISO-conforming system you need to use `member((F->I), Ds)`. Note the parentheses! If you want to express multiple requirements, you need to make small changes to the code that express a *conjunction* of such constraints. I leave this as a very easy exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution but some observations that would not fit a comment.

Don't use lists to represent relations. For example, instead of `[f1, s1]`, write `requires(f1, s1)`. If these requirement are fixed, then define `requires/2` as a predicate. If you need to identify or enumerate features, consider a `feature/1` predicate. For example:

```
feature(f1).
feature(f2).
...
```

Same for `s1`, `s2`, ... E.g.

```
support(s1).
support(s2).
...
```